# True or false?$\left\{x \in\mathbb{R}^3 \mid x_1=0 \right\} \cap\left\{x\in \mathbb{R}^3 \mid x_2=0 \right\}$ is a linear subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, vectors

> True or false? $\left\{x \in\mathbb{R}^3 \mid x_1=0 \right\}
> \cap\left\{x\in \mathbb{R}^3 \mid x_2=0 \right\}$ is a linear subspace
>   of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$

I think the statement is false because if we intersect two vectors we can get a vector of another dimension which won't be of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$?

Let's say this is of the first set $\begin{pmatrix}
0\\ 
1\\ 
0
\end{pmatrix}$ and this is of second set $\begin{pmatrix}
0\\ 
0\\ 
0
\end{pmatrix}$. As intersection we would get $\begin{pmatrix}
0\\ 
0
\end{pmatrix}$ I think? And this would be of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$.

Or I understood things wrong and this is complete daft?

Comment: its the intersection of the whole sets not just 2 items. If you think about it the intersection of those 2 sets will be the elements which have $x_1=0$ and $x_2=0$ now its pretty easy to see if its a subspace

Comment: you are wrong because $(0,0)^{\top}$ isn't the cap you claim and even  isn't in IR^3, but since both sets are linear spaces then its cap it is

Comment: In general . if $V_1$ is linear subspace and $V_2$ is linear subspace their interesection is linear subspace. Try to prove this with the subspace criterias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All vectors such that $x_1 = 0$ and $x_2 = 0$

Looks like
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1 \\
0 \\
x_3
\end{pmatrix} 
\text{AND}
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
x_2 \\
x_3
\end{pmatrix} 
$$

or as I said up there, only $x_3$ is allowed to be non zero.

I think with a little work you can show that what is true about that space. The comments in my opinion are all correct, and you will need to use the subspace criterion to do so formally. But all vectors have dimension three.